# Using Sphinx, how can I remove the title appearing in the side-bar's table of context?

Tags: python-sphinx, tableofcontents

Say my `some.rst` file looks like this:

```
============
My Title
============

1. Section
================

2. Section
=================
```

After compiling, in the resulting `some.html` there will be a table of contents in the side bar that appears as:

> My Title
>
> 1. Section
> 2. Section

Is there a simple way to remove 'My Title' from the table of contents in `some.html`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to use an object type that's ignored by the TOC directive:

```
.. rubric:: My Title
```

This creates text that looks somewhat like a heading, but is excluded from the TOC.  You can update your CSS file with whatever style you want for the `.rubric` class, even mimicking h1 style if you like.

See "[Non-TOC headings within a Restructuredtext page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069405/non-toc-headings-within-a-restructuredtext-page/23549957#23549957)" for how to define rubric styled classes.

Comment: This also breaks the {{ toctree() }} (if you are using it).

Comment: What if we don't have access to the document's content (eg;, `.. include:: x`)? Do you think there is still a workaround. I find it strange that sphinx mixes titles with global toctree.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve this by using the `.. raw:: html` method as described above, with a slight tweak (that avoided breaking the auto-generated TOC). as described earlier, if your file only contains `.. raw:: html` headings, it will break the Sphinx auto-generated TOC. however, if you use `.. raw:: html` and add `---------------------` below it, it won't show on the left-hand nav, and won't break the TOC.
e.g.

so i finally accidentally figured out how to get headings to not be displayed in the left-hand TOC. if your file only contains `.. raw:: html` h2 headings, it will break the sphinx auto-generated TOC (as mentioned in the stackoverflow article). however, if you use `.. raw:: html` and `---------------------` below it, it won't show on the left-hand nav, and won't break the TOC :star2:
e.g.

```
.. raw:: html

   <h2>What Can I Do With KSQL?</h2>

---------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I actually didn't get any errors when I omitted the `---`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to remove it from all of your documents, try [customizing the default template](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/templating.html). Otherwise you will need to modify the [HTML builder](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/builders.html) by creating a subclass.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could modify `localtoc.html` to remove the title from appearing....I cant seem to figure it out just from the docs...thanks for the help

Comment: I can't see how you would do it using localtoc.html. This merely contains a title and a call to {{ toc }}

Answer (score 1):

Very late to this party, I know. I just had this issue, needed to mimic h2 and was not able to edit the style sheet.

My solution ended up being adding raw html in the `some.rst`:

```
:raw-html:`<h1>My Title</h1>`

1. Section
================

2. Section
=================
```

Comment: This breaks the toc tree (if you are using it)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own h3 tag.

For your header you use:

```
|start-h3| My title |end-h3|
```

Later at the end of the file you write:

```
.. |start-h3| raw:: html

     <h3>

.. |end-h3| raw:: html

     </h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are talking about a local TOC (a "on this page" TOC). Unfortunately, Sphinx always prints a document title as first item (`<li>`). Actual local TOC (section titles) are all nested `<ul>` inside the first document title `<li>`. (Yes, it is annoying.)

You have two options:

If current Sphinx theme has local TOC, you have to **tweak produced HTML markup**. For example, by hiding document title using CSS. Copy-pasting from https://techwriter.documatt.com/2021/sphinx-localtoc-remove-document-title.html:

```
.localtoc > ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.localtoc > ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.localtoc > ul > li > a {
  display: none;
}
.localtoc > ul > li > ul {
  // any additional styles to local toc <ul>
}
```

Alternative might be to **manually print local TOC**, e.g. at the beginning of a document with the `contents::` directive and its `:local:` option. Example taken from https://restructuredtext.documatt.com/element/contents.html#no-current-document-title:

```
#################################
Contents without a document title
#################################

Testing ``contents::`` directive with ``:local:`` flag.

.. contents::
   :local:

**********
Section L2
**********

Section L3
==========
```