# Non-TOC headings within a reStructuredText page

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections, tableofcontents

I'm writing some documentation using Sphinx.

Is there a way to format headings within a page which do not become part of the TOC?
Ideally with some hierarchy that is reflected in formatting?

E.g. I want to do

```
My page TOC heading
===================

Subheading (not in TOC, and should be formatted e.g. smaller than the heading)
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Sub-subheading (not in TOC, and formatted e.g. smaller than the subheading)
###########################################################################
```

Any other suggestions for how to markup the text so that it has a more structured appearance for the reader are also welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You can create custom styles for rubrics that mimic your heading styles.

(1) In your ReST source, define custom styles like this:

```
.. role:: style1
    :class: class1

.. role:: style2
    :class: class2
```

Here "style_" is the handle to refer to these in ReST, and "class_" is the CSS class name.

(2) Use the above as inline styles in rubrics:

```
.. rubric:: :style1:`fake H1`

.. rubric:: :style2:`fake H2`
```

(3) In whatever CSS file makes sense, define styles for the new classes:

```
.rubric > .class1 {
    whatever
}

.rubric > .class2 {
    whatever
}
```

Here the "whatever" could be identical to existing styles for H1, H2 etc. if you wish.

Note: in step (3), you could define the CSS selectors more broadly or narrowly.  If the new class names are globally unique, the selector could be as simple as `.class1`; or if you want to use the style just for top-level rubrics like my example, you could use `p.rubric > span.class1` instead.

Answer (score 3):

[Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/), the reference implementation of reStructuredText, upon which Sphinx is built allows you to pass options to the [table of contents directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) which allow you to control how deep you want your table of contents to go into your document hierachy. From the [reStructuredText documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html), the `contents` directive takes a `depth` option:

> depth : integer
>
> The number of section levels that are collected in the table of contents.
>   The default is unlimited depth.

So to get your document structure with only your top level headings included in the table of contents, you could use

```
.. contents: Table of Contents
   :depth: 1
```

**Edit**: It seems that Sphinx implements its own [table of contents directive](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/toctree.html), so you can use

```
.. toctree: Table of Contents
   :maxdepth: 1
```

instead of the first code block above. Also, take a look at the `hidden` option, this might be useful to control further the levels included in the table of contents.

Comment: For now I'm using the depth setting, and with the present document structure, this is not a problem. Structures where there are different depths per branch are not possible, however. A practical example would be an "Introduction" section which I may want to subdivide, but where these divisions are certainly not of the same importance as those of a "Device Administration" section. I'd want the subdivisions of the latter in the TOC, but not those of the former.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to add both `:maxdepth:1` and `:titlesonly:` to the toctree section. This is added in the "parent" rst file (or whichever file contains the `.. toctree::`.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Thanks for sharing!