# Hide specific headings from (python) sphinx toctree while still showing other headings of same depth/level (or deeper)

Tags: python-sphinx, markup, restructuredtext, toctree

Assume I have the following rst file:

**child_file.rst**

```
=========
Chapter
=========
Sample text Sample text Sample text


----------
Section 1
----------
Sample text 

****************
Section 1.1
****************
Sample text Sample text

----------
Section 2
----------
Sample text Sample text Sample text
```

The file is called into a sphinx toctree by another file, so:

**parent_file.rst**

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   child_file.rst
```

Now, I do not want Section 1 to show up in the resulting toctree, but I **do** want Section 1.1 and Section 2 to be included. This means that I cannot just use the`:titlesonly:` option for the `..toctree` directive.

I have seen similar questions for which the answer is to play around with `:maxdepth:`, but I can't do that either since Section 2 is at the same depth as Section 1, and Section 1.1 is even deeper.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `rubric` (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-rubric). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/19069405/407651.